# question if these derivative are equal

Tags: derivatives

Starting fuction: $y= \sqrt{x^2-2x+1}$

derivative A: 
$y^{\prime} = (1/2)(2x-2)(x^2-2x+1)^{-1/2}$

derivative B:  rewrote the starting function as: 
$\sqrt{\left(x-1\right)^2} = \vert x -1 \vert$ thus

$y^{\prime} = $ either 1 if $x > 0$ or -1 if $x < 0$

First, are these the same answer? If they are different please tell me where I went wrong, if they are the same, please explain how and why I can have two different answers?

Comment: The starting point of derivative $B$ should be $y =\sqrt{(x-1)^2}$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. thanks I missed the typo in the question and have hopefully improved it.

Comment: Another typo in third line with the exponents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derivative $A$ is $$ y' = \frac 12 (2x-2) (x^2 - 2x + 1)^{-1/2} = \frac{x-1}{\sqrt{x^2 - 2x + 1}} = \frac{x-1}{|x-1|}.$$

Derivative $B$ should be $1$ if $x > 1$ and $-1$ if $x < 1$.

With this correction observe they agree.

Comment: could you explain how $\frac{x-1}{|x-1|}$ equals the rewrite derivative B?

Comment: do you know the definition of $|x - 1|$?

Comment: its the absolute value.  it is the numerator that I am having trouble with.  Oh.  I now get it as I typed this.  They divide out.